# Compress URL with HTML form GET

Tags: forms, get, gzip

I have a form with too many elements that creates configs, at times the form can't be filled out all the way, so I have been using GET instead of POST to keep the bookmark. However I have come up with over 2000 characters and it's truncating. Trying to compress that portion of the url (beyond the ?) with gzip, or anything easy that will reduce be at least 30%.

At http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html, they explain it can be done, but not how. And here they show the function, but not how to do it on the fly. http://www.rahji.com/wordpress/2005/12/16/compressing-urls/

I am network guy, so I apologize if I am missing something basic.

Comment: Can you explain further why you need to use GET instead of POST?  There may be other ways to make POST work for you.

Comment: Just need a simple method for bookmarking, I have been using it forever, but if I can use post and bookmark simply, sounds like a plan.

Comment: Hm, maybe what you really want is to POST the data, save the current state to the database with a unique ID, and then redirect to a URL containing this ID.

Comment: Sounds a bit more complicated then compressing it, but maybe not, if there any hints you can offer to go this route?